# Eliminating millivolt-level reverse current flow with diode or other

Tags: diodes, usb-c, usb-pd

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fugdpu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am working with [PD Buddy Sink](https://www.tindie.com/products/clarahobbs/pd-buddy-sink/), a small USB-C PD negotiation and power breakout board. It takes USB-C PD input, performs the PD negotiation, and produces DC power. My problem is that the PD Buddy Sink does not block reverse current flow. I am attempting to use this device to charge an SLA battery. I have a SLA-05VDC-SL-A relay-based charge controller just after the sink. The problem is occurring when the relay closes and voltage from my battery bridges through the relay and into the sink's output, causing it to attempt to negotiate with the battery, resulting in a never-ending startup cycle and no resulting "forward" current flow.

I have spoken with the maker of this device and she recommended a diode. I've tried a Schottky 1N5822 and a Rectifier RL207, both of which are leaking reverse voltage on the order of about 15-20 millivolts. This is still too much for the PD Buddy Sink, resulting in the setup cycle.

Is there another solution to my problem to effectively "completely" eliminate reverse current flow from my battery/relay to the sink? I've considered a buck converter to drop the sink's 15-20 volt output to 14.x volts, but not sure if that would prevent the reverse flow I'm working against now.

Comment: What do you mean by "leaking reverse voltage...about 15-20 millivolts"? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. A schematic is better than words. You can add one in using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar. Double-click a component to edit its properties. 'R' = rotate, 'H' = horizontal flip. 'V' = vertical flip. 

Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and "Save and Insert" on the editor an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Apologies for the incorrect terminology. I mean when I use my voltage meter on my SLA battery, I get 12.7 volts. When I put a diode between the volt meter and the battery positive terminal, the diode blocks 12.68 volts, "leaking" approximately 20 millivolts in reverse.

Comment: @NatWest ok, this got me even more confused. Current can be leaked or blocked, voltage not. We'll not be smarter about what you're describing until you add that schematic.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I understand, but there can be no current without voltage, and I'm measuring that. The PD Buddy Sink I'm using doesn't work with current applied to the output. How do I eliminate any potential for that current to flow?

Comment: We have no idea what you're measuring where. Schematic, please. And your terminology abuse gets worse – the only way to eliminate potential would be shorting out your battery until it's empty.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I've added a schematic. In the diagram I've included, my voltage meter is measuring 12.68 volts. I need it to read zero.

Comment: Is it a digital multimeter? Make and model? [Edit] into your quesiton.

Comment: @NatWest thanks! that helps a lot.

Comment: Thanks Marcus. That is a simplified diagram showing my problem. In my real-world scenario, there is a relay between the battery and the diode but the problem is the same with or without the relay. Also, in my real-world scenario, the meter in the schematic is replaced by the PD Buddy Sink, which needs zero voltage to appear from the battery.

Comment: Try putting a bleed resistor in parallel with your meter. Even 10-100 kohm should be okay. If you really need **no** leakage, you'll need a substantially more complex circuit.

Comment: Update the schematic to show the "real-world scenario" along with the relay resistance.

Comment: _"I have a SLA-05VDC-SL-A relay-based charge controller"_ - SLA-05VDC-SL-A is a relay. This tells us **nothing** about your 'charge controller' except that it has a relay on it. Please provide a link to the device. _"...into the sink's output, causing it to attempt to **negotiate** with the battery"_ - what exactly do you mean by 'negotiate'?

Comment: @BruceAbbott they attach a USB-PD fed device to supply a voltage to the SLA battery. USB-PD (power delivery) has a complex protocol (atop a layer that looks *suspiciously* much like ethernet, not even fast ethernet) to negotiate the VBUS voltage with the power supply. That's why you can use your 20V USB-C notebook charger, and use it to charge your 5V phone, or your 12V LiIon battery bank.

Comment: @MarcusMüller but the PD Buddy Sink just produces a voltage, right? How does it 'negotiate' with an SLA battery?

Comment: @BruceAbbott It doesn't. That's just the point. PD Buddy Sink is trying to negotiate with whatever power source attaches to it, which is causing it to continually reset. It should just negotiate with the USB-C side, not the output side.

Comment: @NatWest well that is where I am confused. The PD Buddy Sink is purported to be a replacement for a programmable or fixed power supply, to provide 'the voltage and current your project needs'. Nowhere does the description say that it 'negotiates' with the load. Mind you the documentation is pretty poor, so it is unclear whether whether it can work in continuous current limit (as might be required for charging an SLA battery). Perhaps that is what the OP is talking about.

Comment: @NatWest now I'm confused. How should it "negotiate" with an output side?! Makes no sense – the output is connected via a two-contact screw terminal and is supposed to be a voltage source, not some complex bus. How do you know "negotiation" is the reason for reset? (how do you know it resets?)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Hi again. I know it's attempting negotiation and resetting because it has an LED indicator light. I've sent the light pattern it displays along with the scenario I'm encountering to the manufacturer and she is telling me that's what it's doing. Resistor coming up today...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. The [RL207 datasheet](https://www.rectron.com/data_sheets/rl201-rl207.pdf) explains it.*

If your multimeter has a 10 MΩ input impedance then 1 μA will give V = IR = 1μ × 10M = 10 V. This is very close to what you are seeing.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBlQ5v.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. (a) The circuit redrawn in a more conventional manner with + on top. (b) Loading the circuit.*

Try adding a resistance to shunt the stray current away from the multimeter and measure the voltage again. Report back!

Comment: Now to find a resistor. My garage is not stocked for these kinds of things. I'll probably have to break open something to get one. Would I be able to find one in an AC-DC wall wart?

Comment: After applying a 100 k-ohm resistor, the voltage at the meter went to zero, exactly as you suggested @Transistor. (I'm using a Fluke 179.) But my problem still stands. *Something* inside the PD Buddy Sink is causing it to continually reset when hooked up to the battery. I'm reaching out to the manufacturer for assistance.

Answer (score 0):

So, with the clarifying schematic:

Your diode is in reverse operation, so it will leak very little current. In fact, let's have a look at the reverse current plot:

## RL207

[image: RL207 reverse characteristics]

(rated reverse voltage = 1000V, so you're worst case in the 1% range – reading the urve at [%] = 0 is kind of unscientific, but the takeaway is: < 1µA current leakage.

## 1N5822

[image: 1n5822 reverse characterisitics]

(same here: < 10 µA leakage at 12 V)

## Assessment

Now, how much is 10 µA? Well, your USB devices won't mind these, as even if protection diodes would have to short 10 µA from 12V to ground, that'd be 120 µW of power. The technical term for that is "nothing". I'd say you've "completely" eliminated reverse current flow.

Does it discharge your batter?
You've got a lead-acid battery. These have a typical self-discharge of 4% per month, meaning that just not using it at all will look like there's a resistor connected, discharging it. A month has 720 hours. If your SLA has 1 Ah of capacity, it will lose 4% of 1 Ah in 720 hours. That makes 55 µAh per hour, i.e. a self-discharge current more than 5 times as high than what is leaked.

Comment: Hi Marcus, thanks for this. I'm not concerned about the SLA running low on power when not in use. I'm just trying to eliminate any current getting to my PD Buddy Sink, which can't handle any voltage. Here is the schematic for it: https://cdn.hackaday.io/files/20424873820416/pd-buddy-sink_sch_1.0.pdf

Comment: ... sigh. Voltage doesn't "get anywhere". You're still confusing voltage and current. And I specifically addressed your USB device getting reverse current in my answer!

Comment: My apologies. I'm only measuring voltage hence my consistent misuse of the terminology. I must not be understanding your assessment. I understand that we are talking about a very small amount of current. However, my situation is that whatever current is getting past the diode is too much for the PD sink. I'm going to try the resistor per Transistor's comments and will report back. I don't understand the needs of the PD Buddy Sink (schematic linked above). Might there be something in there that can further clarify my situation to provide a good solution?

Comment: "whatever current is getting past the diode is too much for the PD sink." that is not true. How would that be true? if that was true, your PD sink would be destroyed by random noise.

Comment: @NatWest Ok, let's put it the other way around: you seem to have a source for "even the leakage current of a diode can damage the device". Could you point us to that source? Because honestly, looking through that schematic, I don't find the least indication of that! And it would be pretty senseless to debunk a claim that came from thin air, just as spending an hour debunking that stones can autonomously fly – since they can't, and it's not clear why they even should.

Comment: Hi Marcus, I'm not concerned about the device being damaged. I have never said it would be damaged from this small of a current. Apparently whenever any current comes into the PD Buddy Sink from it's output terminals, it attempts to negotiate the USB-C Power Delivery protocol/handshake on that incoming source, which in my case is the battery. My battery obviously does not support USB-C PD. The PD Buddy Sink attempts the negotiation, then resets, and continually attempts again. I am looking for a way to shunt away any potential current coming into the sink from my battery.

Comment: then, get a resistor, just as @Transistor recommended. But honestly, that sounds like a design fault.

Comment: @NatWest But anyways: an easy way to reproduce a resistor: measure the resitance of D1 with your PDbuddy-thing unplugged from everyting, by attaching your multimeter to the positive and negative contact of the connector where you'd normally attach the battery. Should be pretty high. Now, take a pencil ("lead" pencil, i.e. actually graphite), and try to draw a connection on the board, from one end of D1 to the other. Measure again. If you are lucky, you've been able to bring the resistance down to 1 kΩ to maybe 100 kΩ or so. This will look like a short to the leakage current from the battery,

Comment: but totally doesn't matter in normal operations. Plus: if it doesn't work, you can undo your changes easily by cleaning of your pencil markings

Comment: Super cool Marcus! But I've got a neighbor lending me a resistor tomorrow, so I shall report back!